# use miktex packages from another directory

Tags: packages

Hi

I have downloaded full package of miktex and it has been stored on "‪F:\MikTex_packages" .

And my basic_miktex has been stored on `"C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9"` .

Now my problem is :

How can i  include(import , ... ) and use packages from `"‪F:\MikTex_packages"` to my
`.tex`?

If it is possible give simple code for me.

I'm newbe in tex i would appreciate for your solutions.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Maybe helpful: [How can I manually install a package on MiKTeX (Windows)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2063/124842)

Comment: In the package manager choose "Repository - change package repository" and point it to your folder as local repository.